# How to make framebuffer look like a real monitor?

Tags: linux, framebuffer

I want to create one virtual frame buffer device as i don't have any hardware device and I want work on graphics stuff using frame buffer under Linux System.

Is there a way to make or create Linux framebuffer device (e.g. /dev/fb0 or /dev/fb1 backed by virtual framebuffer) as a real display?

Ideally it should appear in system display settings as a configurable monitor.

Does it require writing some kernel code or it's possible to somehow get away with for example editing X config files or using xrandr?

Please let me know if any one has idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can used XVFB to emulate virtual framebuffer

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb
http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml

Comment: I have installed XVFB in my Linux System but i am not able to find any Virtual Frame Buffer related entries under /dev directory as well as in /proc/fb file. I have also seen in kernel setting using make menuconfig and found that there is one option Linux Virtual Frame Buffer Support which is not enabled and also it is mentioned as "Only for Testing Purpose". Do I need to enable that option in kernel as static or module? Please let me know your feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: You can used module it more easier to remove.
and insmod to load the module.

Comment: I just want to confirm that do i need to enable it as module in kernel configuration to add support of virtual frame buffer?